# Webkit - cannot select field

Tags: php, javascript, html

I'm having trouble with a form - I just can't seem to select the password field. The only way to get to it, is to go to the field using the tab key. This is only affecting webkit browsers.

this is the form html

```
public function form()
{
    global $ACL_LANG;
    $htmlForm = '<form id="frmlogin"><fieldset><label><dl><dt>';
    switch (LOGIN_METHOD) {
        case 'both' :
            $htmlForm .= $ACL_LANG ['USERNAME'] . '/' . $ACL_LANG ['EMAIL'];
            break;
        case 'email' :
            $htmlForm .= $ACL_LANG ['EMAIL'];
            break;
        default :
            $htmlForm .= $ACL_LANG ['USERNAME'];
            break;
    }
    $htmlForm .= '</label></dt>' . '<dd><input type="text" name="u" id="u" class="large" /></dd><dt>' . '<label>' . $ACL_LANG ['PASSWORD'] . '</label></dt>' . '<dd><input type="password" name="p" id="p" class="large" /></dd>' . '<input type="hidden" name="uri" id="uri" value="' . $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] . '" /></dl></fieldset><button type="submit" style="float:right;">Log in</button></form>';
    return $htmlForm;
}
```

This is the javascript governing the page

```
$.getJSON(postFile, function(data) {

    if (data.status == true) {
        // status is authorized
        if (autoRedir) {
            $(authentication).hide();
            $(authenticating).hide().html('Authentication success.').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                window.location = data.url;
            });
        } else {
            $(waitId).fadeOut('slow',
                function() {
                    $(wrapperId).html(data.message).slideDown();
                }).html();
        }
    } else {
        // show form
        $(wrapperId).html(data.message).fadeIn('0', function() {
            // hide  message
            $(waitId).fadeOut('fast',
                function() {

                    //*/ submit handler
                    $("#frmlogin").submit(function() {
                        // loading
                        $(waitId).hide();
                        $(notificationerror).hide();
                        $(notification).hide();
                        $(authentication).fadeIn();
                        $(wrapperId).hide();

                        var _u = $(userId).val();   // form user
                        var _p = $(passId).val();   // form id
                        var _uri = $(uri).val();    // form id

                        //@ valid user ( modify as needed )
                        if (_u.length < 4) {
                            $(authentication).hide();
                            $(notificationerror).html(jsErrMsg).fadeIn('fast', function() {
                            });
                            $(wrapperId).show();
                        }
                        else {
                            //@ valid password ( modify as needed )
                            if (_p.length < 4) {
                                $(authentication).hide();
                                $(waitId).html(notificationerror).fadeIn('fast', function() {
                                    $(passId).focus();
                                });
                            }
                            else {
                                $.post(postFile, { u: _u, p: _p, uri: _uri }, function(data) {
                                        if (data.status == true) {
                                            if (autoRedir) {
                                                $(authentication).html('Setting session.').fadeIn();
                                                 setTimeout("",2000);
                                                $(authentication).html('Authentication success.').fadeIn('fast', function() {
                                                    window.location = data.url;
                                                });
                                            } else {
                                                $(waitId).fadeOut('slow',
                                                    function() {
                                                        $(wrapperId).slideUp('slow', function() {
                                                            $(this).html(data.message).slideDown();
                                                        });
                                                    }).html();
                                            }
                                        } else {
                                            $(wrapperId).show();
                                            $(notification).show();
                                            $(authentication).hide();
                                            $(notificationerror).html(data.message).fadeIn(function() {
                                            });
                                        }
                                    }
                                    , 'json');
                            }
                        }
                        return false;
                    });
                    //*/
                }).html();
        });

    }

});
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Don't build up forms like that; use templates.

Comment: That call to `setTimeout("", 2000)` will do nothing useful.

Comment: @DhaivatPandya, changing the whole system now would add more time and not produce useful results.

Comment: It will definitely produce useful results - you'll spend a s**t ton less time working on problems with convoluted code like this.

Comment: With 4 hours to fix this, I don't think spending time on this would be wise. It might be something worth looking at when the software goes through refactoring.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like if you can tab to the field but cant click onto it there's something overlaying it... therefore getting in the way.

If you open the site in Google Chrome... right click where you're trying to access the input box but getting blocked. Select 'Inspect Element' and it should highlight which element your mouse right clicked on.

You can also hover your mouse over elements in the inspector to highlight them on the page. This might reveal what's blocking it.